# Facebook search by url parameters documentation

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-search

Facebook can be queried by the web gui (GraphSearchQuery) but also by url 
Example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=stackexchange%20facebook&
filters_rp_creation_time={"start_year"%3A"2011"%2C"end_month"%3A"2011-01"}&
filters_rp_location=155428381137989
```

This filters_rp_location maps to 40°42'32.5"N+74°00'24.2"W

Does someone know where I can find more documentation on these url-parameters?

Answer (score 3):

There is no public documentation on these parameters.

The `filters_rp_location` seems to just take a Facebook ID. In your case `155428381137989` which is https://www.facebook.com/pages/110-William-St-New-York-NY/155428381137989

If you're looking to use Facebook Graph Search, you will have to build the query

So, a query for posts at "110 William St New York, NY"

`https://www.facebook.com/search/str/155428381137989/stories-at`

A query for posts with the words "stackexchange facebook"

`https://www.facebook.com/search/str/stackexchange%20facebook/stories-keyword`

A query to match the year "2011"

`https://www.facebook.com/search/2011/date/stories`

Then finally an intersection of all three queries

For example

`https://www.facebook.com/search/str/155428381137989/stories-at/str/stackexchange%20facebook/stories-keyword/2011/date/stories/intersect`

The above intersection query doesn't work (either because Facebook Search is failing or there actually is no data there), but you get the idea.

For completeness here is another example

Results for 2013 for the string Richard: `https://www.facebook.com/search/str/155428381137989/stories-at/str/richard/stories-keyword/2013/date/stories/intersect`

No Results in 2016: `https://www.facebook.com/search/str/155428381137989/stories-at/str/richard/stories-keyword/2016/date/stories/intersect`